# CookieParser vs req.cookies expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

When I read about `req.cookies` in [expressjs docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.cookies),

> When the cookieParser() middleware is used this object defaults to {},
>   otherwise contains the cookies sent by the user-agent.

And when I read about [CookieParser middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieParser),

> Parses the Cookie header field and populates req.cookies with an object keyed by the cookie names.

So, `req.cookies` says if I use CookieParser, it will be set to `{}`, but CookieParser says it will populate `req.cookies`.

My question is Why do we need CookieParser, if `req.cookies` itself gives the cookies?

Comment: The first document is wrong. It should be "When the cookieParser() middleware is used this object contains the cookies sent by the user-agent, if there no cookie found it is {}. Checking it for null or undefined are not necessary".

Comment: Indeed, it defaults to an empty object, and if there are any cookies they will be stored with keys and values in that same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a documentation issue. I created a [`bug`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1859) for this problem.

Quoting the [Actual response](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1859#issuecomment-30449882)

> just bad grammar on my part, I meant to say that when you use
>   cookieParser() the req.cookies object is populated. Otherwise it
>   doesn't exist. There's a lot of cross-documentation going on because
>   most people use Express as if Connect barely exists

Comment: Unfortunately, four months later, the express docs still have it confusingly worded.

Answer (score 6):

Without using `cookieParser`, cookies come as an URL-encoded header ("`Cookie`").

This means that, by default, the cookie information is to find in `req.headers.cookie`.

As the name implies, `cookieParser` *parses* the contents of the `Cookie` header (utilizing the aptly-named [cookie](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-cookie)-module) and conveniently places the result (an object keyed by the cookie names) in `req.cookies` for your enjoyment.

I'd encourage you to look at the [source code](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) of `cookieParser` to better understand why it even exists in the first place.

Comment: But the documentation says, req.cookies will contain `the cookies sent by the user-agent.` if `cookieParser` is not used, right? And there is no reference to `req.headers.cookie` in express's documentation :(

Comment: @thefourtheye The way it's written is unfortunate, I'll agree. It gets grammatically technical here but there's a comma (,) before the *"otherwise"* part which means that we're still in the context of *"When the `cookieParser()`"* and thus the *"otherwise"* refers to when using `cookieParser` and actually having cookie data :)